# problem in integrating admob in an android app

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an application and now i am trying to integrate admob ads.

I have gone through the instructions on [found on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#adactivity) but I still have some errors.

I have added the jar file, I have added the permissions in the manifest file, and I've added `android:value ="axxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` under the activity where i want to show the admobs.

I have created the attrs.xml file in values and it contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.google.ads.AdView">
      <attr name="adSize">
          <enum name="BANNER" value="1"/>
          <enum name="IAB_MRECT" value="2"/>
          <enum name="IAB_BANNER" value="3"/>
          <enum name="IAB_LEADERBOARD" value="4"/>
      </attr>
      <attr name="axxxxxxxxxxxxx" format="string"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then in the layout.xml file of the activity where I want the admob I have added the following lines:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="25px"
>

<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="axxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here an error is shown:
`The prefix "ads" for attribute "ads:adUnitId" associated with an element type "com.google.ads.AdView" is not bound.`

In my activity class i have added the following line
    RelativeLayout rl2 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.widget32);

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Here the `R.id.adView` has a red underline indicating an error.

What does this mean and how do I resolve my errors? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this to your layout:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/YOUR_APP_P"
```

Comment: This is now incorrect in Admob 4.1.0 see [this google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5) (look for Tim's post).